# Strava Metro users, how to interpret BIKECNTN?

Tags: strava

Glasgow city provides its Strava user's stats created 2013 (link below). The CSV file contains all the expected columns including, "AMCOMMUTEN" "PMCOMMETN" "BIKECNTN" and so on.

However, when we look at the row values, some are a little off., particularly in the bike count columns. The values are not whole integers as I would expect, instead the values are much smaller, for example, .0930053, 0.0196534.

First, I thought these we the percentage of users on a section of road. However when I tested this idea, it was nullified. The total values in BIKECNTN for example, add up to 2436.940338.

Further - I notice in a youtube video (linked below) that BIKECNTN values are defined as whole numbers. Any ideas on why are the Glasgow numbers so small?

screenshot of Glasgow values less than whole integers - https://1drv.ms/i/s!AtadKSvlHF4EhD9yTFGwX1WHPRJu

youtube video (see 30 minutes in for table) - https://youtu.be/eHGLNQnxcNs

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure where you got this from, but I'm guessing it was from [the Glasgow Data Portal](https://data.glasgow.gov.uk)? If so afraid [there isn't any  metdata](https://data.glasgow.gov.uk/dataset/journey-statistics-by-cyclists-who-use-strava/resource/16c6a315-563a-4478-a58d-69bacc9a7cec?inner_span=True) :(

I found some [metadata here](http://ubdc.ac.uk/media/1323/stravametro_200_user_guide_withoutpics.pdf), but I don't see that column name in there.

I had a look at the data using QGIS (to join the OSM road network to the strava data on field osm_id). Coloured it using 'graduated', 10 classes, Jenks Breaks going from grey (low) thru yellow (medium) to white (high) and got this...

[image: glasgow strava map]

That looks plausible, but without knowing the units it's difficult to know. Maybe they may have been normalised (squeezed down into a smaller range)? BIKECNTN = Bike Count Normalised (?)

(The reason for "jenks breaks" is that it finds clusters of similar values, which reveal patterns you won't see in the data if you just assume they're evenly distributed. "quantiles" are also useful for this.)

Comment: I was able to develop the same, and I agree that it looks as it should for a cycling density map. Especially considering local use. For example, the white line  around the centre of the map is a national cycle route that runs along the river. It's very popular. Further, in the lower left-hand corner, there's a yellow route - this is a popular route used by recreational cyclists to enter and exit the city. 

I've asked the city for some input. Let's see if they have the answer!  Thanks for the input!!